# Telegram Bot API не отправляет файл?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

С наступающим! (для всех, читающих в 2020 - с наступившим!) )

Не могу разобраться с ботом - пытаюсь отправить себе файл с ПК.
Собственно, в чем суть бота: дома, в домашней сети wifi стоит Rasbery PI в качестве сервера, на котором в цикле крутится серверная часть с ботом - бот принимает url, по которому нужно сохранить web страницу локально на внешний usb подключенный к малине. Но, я так же, хочу иметь доступ к сохраненным файлам не только в домашней сети, а делать статический ip на малине (на ней так же стоит apache и COPS (OPDS каталогизатор)) - не хочется, поэтому, организовал "общение" все через того же бота:
Собственно, "общение" с ботом (знаю, что можно сделать клавиатуру с кнопками, но это больше тренировочный проект - для себя и тут мне даже интереснее сделать велосипед)

```
if (e.Message.Text.StartsWith("$"))//command
        {
            switch (e.Message.Text)
            {
                case "$help":
                    bot.SendTextMessageAsync(new Telegram.Bot.Types.ChatId(id), "send me some commands:\n $help  -to see commands list\n" +
                        "$books_log - to see list of saved books (from log file)\n $books_list - to see list of saved books(get files name from storage)\n $download - to download some article");
                    break;
                case "$books_log":
                    bot.SendTextMessageAsync(new Telegram.Bot.Types.ChatId(id), File.ReadAllText("URLLogs.txt"));
                    break;
                case "$books_list":
                    GetBooksList();
                    break;


                default:
                    if (e.Message.Text.StartsWith("$download"))
                    {
                        string pathToFile = GetDownloadFilePath(e.Message.Text.Substring(e.Message.Text.IndexOf(" ") + 1), e);
                        try
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(pathToFile))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("file exist");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("file NOT exist");
                            }



                            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
                            {
                                InputOnlineFile iof = new InputOnlineFile(stream);
                                iof.FileName = "";
                                var send = bot.SendDocumentAsync(new Telegram.Bot.Types.ChatId(id), iof, "Сообщение");
                            }

                            //bot.SendDocumentAsync(new Telegram.Bot.Types.ChatId(id), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles.InputOnlineFile(pathToFile));

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

**Суть проблемы:** код отрабатывает, без ошибок, в консоль выводится, что файл существует, но сам файл (htm страницу) - я не получаю.